# Calculate last day of quarter with date binary in a simpler/better way

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a simpler/better way to calculate the last day of the quarter with date, than the one I've come up with?

```
#QUARTER=$(( ((($(date +'%-m') - 1) / 3) + 1) ))
#LAST_MONTH_QUARTER=$(( 3 * ${QUARTER} ))

LAST_DAY_QUARTER=$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d"$(date +%Y)-$(( 3 * ((($(date +'%-m') - 1) / 3) + 1) ))-01 + 1 month - 1 day")
[[ "$(date +"%Y%m%d")" == "${LAST_DAY_QUARTER}" ]] && echo OK || echo NOK
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Could you clarify your question by giving an example of how you want to call the function or script, and how smart you want it to be about business days vs weekend, and things like this?

Answer (score 1):

GNU `date`'s output format has the specifier `%q  quarter of year (1..4)`. With that you can easily retrieve the current quarter. However, the input format doesn't seem to recognize quarters in any way.

As the last day of each quarter is always the same `MMDD`, regardless of the year, it might be easier and more clear to use a lookup table.

```
lastDay=(. 0331 0630 0930 1231)
quarter=$(date +%q)
echo "$(date +%Y)${lastDay[quarter]}"
```

If you want to eliminate a possible bug at the last millisecond of each year use

```
lastDay=(. 0331 0630 0930 1231)
read year quarter <<< "$(date +'%Y %q')"
echo "$year${lastDay[quarter]}"
```

If your implementation of `date` does not support `%q` you may have to resort to the calculation `quarter = (month-1) / 3` or use a bigger lookup table

```
lastDay=(0331 0630 0930 1231)
read year month <<< "$(date +'%Y %-m')"
echo "$year${lastDay[--month/3]}"
```

```
lastDay=(. 0331{,,} 0630{,,} 0930{,,} 1231{,,})
read year month <<< "$(date +'%Y %-m')"
echo "$year${lastDay[month]}"
```

Comment: Specifically, GNU date has %q. The BSD date found in macos does not.

Comment: If you're being paranoid, `IFS=" " read year quarter <<< "$(date +'%Y %q')"`

Comment: Thanks for the info! After doing some research, %q was apparently added in coreutils 8.26 or 8.27 and CentOS 7 unfortunately only provides version 8.22

Comment: @Juntao Did you ever try the 2nd solution using `%m` instead of `%q`? Were there any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d=$(date +%Y-%m); m=$((10#${d#*-}-1)); date +%F --date="$(date +${d%-*}-$((m-m%3+1))-01) + 3 month - 1 day"
```

You can proof it with e.g.:

```
for d in 2021-{01..12}; do 
  printf '%s : ' "$d"
  m=$((10#${d#*-}-1))
  date +%F --date="$(date +${d%-*}-$((m-m%3+1))-01) + 3 month - 1 day"
done
```

**Notes:**

- The first command `d=$(date +%Y-%m)` get the time as atomic operation. Getting year and month by 2 date commands will give wrong values if the year changes bewteen.
- `10#` forces interpretation as decimal number. Otherwise months `08` and `09` are scanned as invalid octal number.
- Surround the command by `(...)` to remove side effects (variables `d` and `m`).

Comment: Doesn't look much less complex than his own approach.

Comment: @Wiimm : I've been trying to figure out in which case this could happen but without success. Can you explain your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

date in coreutils < 8.26

```
date +"%Y%m%d" -d"$(date +%Y)-$(( 3 * ((($(date +'%-m') - 1) / 3) + 1) ))-01 + 1 month - 1 day"
```

date in coreutils >= 8.26

```
date +"%Y%m%d" -d"$(date +%Y)-$(( 3 * $(date +'%q') ))-01 + 1 month - 1 day"
```